# Are there languages that are not in RE nor CO-RE?

Tags: computability

I am familiar with the theorem which states that some languages are not in the RE (Recursively Enumerable) class of languages, but that can mean either that they are all in CO-RE (or rather, the part of it that doesn't intersect with RE), or that they are partly in CO-RE and partly somewhere else.

Are there languages about which nothing can be decided, not even what words are *not* in them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Yes**, there are some. There is actually an infinite hierarchy of languages which are *less and less* decidable, namely the [Arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). Recursively Enumerable languages and their complements are at its level 1. An example of language which isn't RE or coRE is the set of Turing machines computing total functions.

Answer (score 11):

To complement Michael Blondin’s nice answer, actually there are *many* languages which are not in RE or in coRE or even in the arithmetic hierarchy in the following sense: there are ℵ languages, but there are only ℵ<sub>0</sub> languages in the arithmetic hierarchy!

Comment: {<M, i> : L(M) is in level i of the arithmetic hierarchy} being such a language

Comment: @Michael: I do not think that I know enough about the computability theory to understand your comment.  How is your M encoded?

Comment: I was giving an example of a language which isn't in the hierarchy. Given the description of a Turing machine M and a natural number i, the problem of determining whether the language of M is in the level i (but not i+1) of the arithmetic hierarchy isn't in the arithmetic hierarchy, otherwise we'd get a contradiction.

Comment: @Michael: I still cannot understand.  If M is a Turing machine, I think that L(M) is necessarily in RE by the definition of RE.

Comment: Perhaps he meant machines with access to oracles?

Comment: @Philip: Then my question would be, to which oracle?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, I was thinking that perhaps it is an encoding scheme that permits access to an indefinite number of oracles for languages in the arithmetic hierarchy.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, my comment doesn't make any sense. Here is a good language: {<x, i> : x is in the i^th Turing jump of the empty set of the arithmetic hierarchy}.

Comment: @Michael: That seems good.  For those who do not know what the Turing jump is (I did not), see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump).

Comment: Michael's first example can be defined as $\{$ $(\varphi,k): \varphi $ is an arithmetical (i.e. first-order arithmetic) formula expressible using only k quantifier alternations $\}$. A simpler set would be $\{$  $(\varphi(x),n) : \varphi(x)$ is an arithmetical (i.e. first-order arithmetic) formula and $\varphi(n)$ is true $\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Michael and Tsuyoshi's answers are great, but I'm surprised that no one was precise about just how many languages are not in the first level of the arithmetic hierarchy. Michael said that "some" and Tsuyoshi said that "many" languages are in neither RE nor co-RE. In fact (as Tsuyoshi implicitly put in his answer) *almost every* language is in neither RE nor co-RE. This essentially comes from the fact that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ languages and only $\aleph_0$ Turing machines.

Comment: That is what I meant in my answer, but thanks for pointing out the correct term to use!