# Is $ALL\setminus(RE \cup co-RE)$ empty?

Tags: computability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there languages that are not in RE nor CO-RE?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/are-there-languages-that-are-not-in-re-nor-co-re)

Let [$ALL$](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:A#all) be the language of all decision problems. My question is, is there a language that is neither recognizable or complement-recognizable? If such a language exists, I believe it would be very interesting to study it (if it is possible!).

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think [AH](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:A#ah) is a subset of ALL. So, if AH does not collapse, $ALL\setminus(RE \cup co-RE)$ is nonempty.

Comment: Complexity Zoo: "Each level of AH strictly contains the levels below it." That should answer your question.

Comment: Robin, Sadeq, thank you for your comments and your links. I know of the polynomial hierarchy and I've heard of the arithmetical hierarchy, which turns out to be exactly what I was looking for. Can you post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it? If not, should I just close the question?

Comment: "Given a computable predicate $P$, decide whether $P(x)$ is both 'true' and 'false' infinitely many times for positive integers $x$."  Neither the positive nor negative result can be verified in a finite amount of time.

Comment: chazisop, this is not a research-level question (the answer can be found in the first chapters of almost *any* computability textbook or on Wikipedia). I am therefore closing the question as off-topic.

Comment: @Kaveh: This is a duplicate of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/are-there-languages-that-are-not-in-re-nor-co-re.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, thanks. I will make it closed as duplicate (though I sincerely think this is *really* not research-level, see [Computability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory)).

Comment: You are both correct. Upon having the AH mentioned I realized this is well below research-level (my background in computability is of undergraduate level). Unfortunately, I was searching for recognizable and unrecognizable and that duplicate didn't come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting my comment as an answer, at the request of the OP.

[Arithmetic Hierarchy](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aA#ah) AH is a class of decision problems defined as below:

Let $Δ_0 = \Sigma_0 = \Pi_0 = R$. Then for $i>0$, let

- $Δ_i = R^ {\Sigma_{i-1}}$.
- $\Sigma_i = RE ^{\Sigma_{i-1}}$.
- $\Pi_i = coRE ^{\Sigma_{i-1}}$.

Obviously, AH $\subseteq$ ALL. On the other hand, "each level of AH strictly contains the levels below it." (As pointed by Robin Kothari in a comment above). Therefore, $ALL\setminus(RE \cup coRE)$ is nonempty.

Comment: It's also worth noting that AH doesn't exhaust ALL either - the AH consists essentially of the (union of) the finite jumps of the recursive degree *0*, and the operation can be iterated through countable ordinals beyond $\omega$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump for more details.